# "Проснулся (в) без четверти семь"

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно?
Я полагаю, что правильным будет *проснулся в без четверти семь*, поскольку во всех других подобных случаях предлог "в" наличествует: «проснулся в семь», «проснулся в пять минут восьмого», «проснулся в полседьмого» и т. п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это раньше было неправильно, а сейчас **нормально** – наверное, догадались, что два предлога подряд **без особой надобности** употреблять не стоит.

А вообще говоря, **референция у В.п.** относительно временной шкалы **очень неопределенная** и зависит от наблюдателя и масштабов наблюдаемых временных отрезков (минуты, часы, дни и т.д.)

**Точечное указание (предлог В)** нужен не так часто, например: *Каждое утро в половине восьмого он поворачивал со Стачек на Волынкину, форсировал пригорок и **в без пятнадцати** уже был на «Свободе».* [Ксения Букша, 2013].

В остальных же случаях такая точность ни к чему, например: **Сегодня я проснулся **без четверти семь**.**

К примеру, мы можем сказать: ***Последние дни (в последние дни)** перед отъездом  мы встречались или звонили друг другу часто.*

И это тоже зависит от временных масштабов наблюдателя, когда период кажется точечным или протяженным объектом.

Comment: Аргументация про "тогда" и "сейчас" не выглядит убедительной, поскольку писали по-разному и "тогда", и "сейчас". Так что мой вопрос был про правильность не с точки зрения анализа Нацкорпуса, а с точки зрения языковой логики. Логика же языка, я полагаю, выступает за "в без". "Я проснулся в семь без четверти": инверсия, и если вернуть на место, то куда денется "в"? Предлог не может просто пропасть.

Comment: Про Нацкорпус это я так, к слову, а все остальное как раз про языковую логику. Инверсия здесь ни при чем, логика же в особенностях  В. падежа при обозначении времени.  Лингвисты этой теме уделяют особое внимание, а я же так, кое-что пересказала.  А если без конкретики, то язык не не по одной мерке скроен,  и все в нем оптимально и разумно. Неужели без предлога В понять смысл вашего предложении  никак не возможно.  А вот два предлога подряд - это как-то странно смотрится и похоже на формализм и  неоправданное стремление ко всему одинаковому

Comment: А если мне нужно показать точность и именно что одинаковость: персонаж проснулся, как всегда, в без четверти семь. В таком случае уместно?

Comment: Если собираетесь все утро расписывать по минутам, то да, точность нужна.  А если одинаковость уже обозначена наречием "как всегда", то делать это необязательно. Как-то нарочито выглядит ваш предлог В, будто в нем коннотация какая.